# How to determine the userid f person who has opened the table in UNIX

Tags: unix, sas

Is it possible to find out the userid of person who has opened the table while updation on that table goes on. I generally gets an error like "A lock is held by process 28036".
    It will really helpful if anyone can guide me on this.

Comment: Do you need the unix command to print the uid?

Comment: Yes a unix command will work. I am not sure if its possible or not, i run my code on SAS.

Comment: I don't aware of sas. Just try `echo $UID`

Comment: It isn't working. I just have the process number through which i need to know the ID, the one who has opened the table

Comment: No its stillnot working.I am getting below error: 
lsof: cannot open /dev/kmem
lsof: kvm_open(namelist=default, corefile=default): Permission denied

Comment: `sudo` it, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `ps -fp 28036 | tail -1 | awk 'print $1'`. That should give you the username of the owner of the process. It also does not require SU privileges.

Comment: That works!!! Thanks.. The only change in the above code: ps -fp 6634 | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'